# How to extend route of one RestController with another one in Spring?

Tags: spring, routes, spring-restcontroller

I have two controllers

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    List<Person> getPersons(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Another one for child entities that belong to "person"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person/{parentId}/book")
public class BookController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    List<Book> getBooksOfPerson(@PathParam("parentId") Integer parentId){
        ...
    }

}
```

If I call /person I want to trigger the PersonController to get me all Persons, however if I call /person/1/book I want to trigger the BookController to get me all books of the person with ID 1.

**Is it possible to solve that somehow without messing my separated controllers up, like defining a kind of placeholder like in my example above?**

Comment: I'm confused by your question - I think what you've shown above should work, with the exception that in `BookController` you've named the parameter `param` in the `@RequestMapping` annotation and `id` in the `@PathParam` annotation. What are you seeing when you try that?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I didn´t know this is indeed working, in case I´m calling /person/1/books the parentId will always be null. When I call /person/1/books/2 instead, both id´s getting passed to the method.

Comment: In the case of `/person/1/books` the `parentId` will be `null` because you've called it `{param}` in the `@RequestMapping`, but `id` in the `@PathParam`. If you make those two names match your `parentId` should get the value.

Comment: In your second example (`/person/1/books/2`) I don't know what you mean by "both id's getting passed to the method" - how can multiple values be set in a single method parameter?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I´ve changed it to parentId in my code, as well as @PathParam("parentId") Integer parentId in the args. In the second example I have a method like Book getBook(@PathParam("parentId") Integer parentId, @PathParam("id") Integer bookid) which will give me both path params as a result

Comment: OK - so my edit reflects what your code actually looks like then? I'm not sure what the question is - it sounds like everything's working as you want it.